# Why is the value of variable in solidity state empty?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have the following code

```
contract User {
    using strings for *;
     address public DB;
    function User(address _DB) {
        if(_DB == 0x0) throw;
        DB = _DB;
    }
    function setUser(string name, string email) public {
        UserLibrary.setUser(DB, msg.sender, name, email);
    }
```

1. After the deploy of the contract, on remix when i try to fetch the value of DB from the contract, It says `call to EthMeetUser.DB` and nothing else.
2. During the debug of `setUser` in remix, DB in the solidity state is `0x0X`

**UPDATE:**

I used to use `Ganache` and it will run on the port `7545` by default and I set the environment in remix as `web3 provider` and the above mentioned problem appears, 
Similarly if I set the environment to `Javascript VM` the problem doesn't appear.

Not sure what I have been doing wrong. Someone please point me right?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I added `pragma solidity ^0.4.19;` to the top, deleted `using strings...` and `function setUser...`, and added the missing closing curly brace. Then I deployed the contract in Remix, passing "0x01234678901234678901234567890123456789" as the constructor argument. Then I clicked the button next to "DB" and got that value back.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @smarx . I changed the environment from local `web3provider` that I used from `ganache` to `Javascript VM` ropsten network and its working like you have experienced. How could this be different?

Comment: I can't reproduce with `ganache` either. I'm confused what you mean when you say "Javascript VM ropsten network." Those are two different things. Which one is working for you?

Comment: @smarx I ran `ganache` it runs it in port `7545`. Now In remix I choose the environment as `web3 provider` and it asks me for the localhost with port and i provide 7545, Then I can create contracts, but then on click on button next to "DB" i get it blank. 
But this issue is not reproducible when environment is set to Javascript VM.

Comment: Odd, I believe the default is port 8545. So when you said "Javascript VM ropsten network" you just meant the JavaScript VM? Or have you also tested on Ropsten (and if so, what were the results)? I can't reproduce the issue with the JavaScript VM or with ganache. Both work fine for me.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant just Javascript VM. And Ganache runs default in port 7545. May be I'm facing some local machine issue. Let me try with ropsten or rinkeby and then come to a conclusion. Even then I donot know why this would happen.